# FFmpeg Error Checking

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, avi, error-checking

I have three example videos, `good.avi`, `damaged1.avi`, and `damaged2.avi`. The first will play in VLC, but the second two both error with the same "Broken or missing AVI Index" message.

I have thousands of these videos which I need to process in MATLAB, so I'm trying to error check using FFmpeg like this: `ffmpeg -v error -i vidname.avi -f null - 2>&1`

Now here's the part I don't understand:
On `good.avi` it completes with no output -OK
On `damaged1.avi` it outputs `[mjpeg @ 0x7fc1dd813800] overread 1` -OK
On `damaged2.avi` it completed with no output as in `good.avi` -?????

Would someone with video codec/FFmpeg experience please help me understand what's going on here so I can develop a more robust error check?

They also both have identical codec details in VLC:
[image]

Comment: Does ffplay play damaged2.avi?

Comment: Sort of, it freezes about half way through with no error message. On the other hand for damaged1.avi, it freezes with an error message at about 2/3 through.

Comment: What happens if you rewrap: `ffmpeg -i damaged2.avi -c copy test2.avi`

Comment: Hmm rewrapping damaged2.avi allows test2.avi to be played with VLC, but rewrapping damaged1.avi still shows "Broken or missing AVI Index" when trying to play test1.avi

Answer (score 2):

This is a long shot, but I suspect one of the JPEG image is corrupted (due to the `overread 1` error message).

Try to extract the images from `damaged1.avi`

```
ffmpeg -i damage1.avi -vcodec copy image%d.jpg
```

then run `mogrify` on the extracted images:

```
for i in image*.jpg; do mogrify "$i"; done
```

Finally, recreate the video:

```
cat image*.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -c:v mjpeg -i - output.avi
```

If this works, then you can extract the audio from damage1.avi and multiplex it into output.avi.

Comment: Thanks, the main issue though is being able to automate the identification of these damaged files. I don't really need this one particular video, but if I try to read it into Matlab the program crashes, and I have ~50,000 of these videos to process so if I leave it running over night and one of these gets read in it will crash and halt my progress. So mainly I need a way to check for this damage. For instance in damaged1.avi I can properly check for it, but in damaged2.avi I'm not able to.